# Optimized solution for reading from a file, manipulating its data and writing to another file in JAVA

Tags: java, memory, io

I have a file "File 1" containing approximately 0.1 million lines.

I have to read this file line by line and add some text to each line and write it to another file "File 2".

I don't want to perform write operation on "File 2" for each line as its expensive.

Which is the better option to save each modified line of "File 1" in memory?

ArrayList or StringBuilder or anything else?

And at the end I will write the complete data in memory to "File 2".

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 1):

Using an appropriately sized buffer might not be as expensive as you might think. Keeping all of the content in memory when your problem looks to be more of a stream processing one sounds like a bad idea.

Reading File 1 from a `BufferedReader`, changing something and passing the result to a `BufferedWriter` might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use BufferedOutputStream to reduce number of physical writes:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream ("input.txt")));
Writer writer = 
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream ("output.txt")));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
{
    writer.write (line + " foo \n");
}

reader.close ();
writer.close ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont think reading it line by line will huge performance impact , if you are using java 5 and above you can make use of java.nio to make use of native OS processes

Check this link for more info

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html